# How to increment a filename in javascript based on existing filenames

Tags: javascript, arrays, while-loop, comparison

I am creating a javascript program that allows images to be uploaded to a drag and drop zone, not allowing duplicate filenames. If i have the following filenames already uploaded (will just use strings for convienience in this case):

["image1.png","image2.png","image3.png","image.png"]

And I want to upload another image with the name "image.png", how can i continuously loop over the previous array, comparing the new value whilst incrementing the filename based on if the value is found.

The expected result is that the new image will be "image4.png".

I realise that this may possibly require some combination of both for and while loops but I am unable to figure out the exact conditionals required to achieve this.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One method is to keep incrementing the count by 1 while that combination of name and number exists in the array (checked with `Array#includes`).

```js
let names = ["image1.png","image2.png","image3.png","image.png"];
let newName = "image.png";
let [, name, ext] = newName.match(/^(\w+)(\.\w+)$/);
let count = 0;
while (names.includes(name + (count ? count : "") + ext)) {
  ++count;
}
console.log('final name:', name + (count ? count : "") + ext);
```